# How to modify a function to meet certain properties?

Tags: calculus, functions, dynamical-systems

I want to modify

$$B(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & : x > 0\\
    0 & : x \leq 0
  \end{array}
\right.$$

so that the new function

$$C(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    0 & : x \leq 0\\
    1 & : x \geq 1
  \end{array}
\right.$$

and also that $C'(0) > 0$ if $0 < x < 1$.

I tried $B(\frac{x}{1 - x})$, but it doesn't stay at $1$ when $x \geq 1$.

Comment: Why not $1-B(x)e^{1/x^2}$? EDIT: Whoops, missed the last requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Take $C(x)=\frac{B(x)}{B(x)+B(1-x)}$.